# Magento get manufacturer labels ONLY for a particular store

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get manufacturer labels only for a particular store, but it's not working and I always get all manufacturers (of all stores). Any ideas?  Thats my code:

```
    $entityTypeIdentifier = 'catalog_product';
    $attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
    $storeId = 2;
    $attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute'); 
    $attributeId = 
    $attributeModel->getIdByCode($entityTypeIdentifier,$attributeCode); 
    $attribute = $attributeModel->load($attributeId); 
    $attribute->setStoreId( $storeId ); 
    $attributeOptionsModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table');
    $attributeTable = $attributeOptionsModel->setAttribute($attribute); 
    $options = $attributeOptionsModel->getAllOptions(false);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($options);
```

`$attribute->setStoreId( $storeId );` is ignored and thats the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 204
            [label] => 3M ESPAÑA
        )
.
.
.
```

Thats eav_attribute_option_value table:

value_id
option_id
store_id
value

1263
204
0
3M ESPAÑA

1264
204
1
3M ESPAÑA

Comment: I assume you are trying to dump manufacturers that only used by store #2. Magento will always dump an option's value whether it has store specific value or not.

If you have "3M ESPAÑA" value for option #204 on store ids #0 and #1, Magento will return store #0 value for store #2 as default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In getAllOptions function of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table class, an option's value will be returned whether it has store specific value or not.

For example, if you have 100 options for an attribute and store #2 has values for 20 of them, option model will return 100 options whether you setStoreId(2) or not. If you set store id, model will return 20 of them in store #2 value, other 80 options in default value.

But if you need an answer to get only that 20 values, here you are my friend:

```
$entityTypeIdentifier = 'catalog_product';
$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
$storeId = 2;

$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection   = $resource->getConnection('read');
$query = $connection->select()
    ->from(array('e' => $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute')), array())
    ->joinLeft(array(
        'f' => $resource->getTableName('eav/entity_type')),
        "e.entity_type_id = f.entity_type_id AND f.entity_type_code = '$entityTypeIdentifier'",
        array()
    )
    ->joinLeft(array(
        'g' => $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option')),
        'e.attribute_id = g.attribute_id',
        array()
    )
    ->joinRight(
        array('h' => $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option_value')),
        "g.option_id = h.option_id AND h.store_id = $storeId",
        array('h.option_id', 'h.value')
    )
    ->where('e.attribute_code = ?', $attributeCode);
$options = $connection->fetchAssoc($query);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($options);
```

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I need, it works like a charm :)